# Pion decay $\pi^{+} \rightarrow e^{+}\nu_{e}$ and $\pi^{+} \rightarrow \mu^{+}\nu_{\mu}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, kinematics, standard-model, pions

I have a quick question:

I want to calculate how much more likely we *expect* the process $\pi^{+} \rightarrow e^{+}\nu_{e}$ to be in comparison to $\pi^{+} \rightarrow \mu^{+}\nu_{\mu}$.

I *know* that in nature, the process $\pi^{+} \rightarrow \mu^{+}\nu_{\mu}$ occurs almost exclusively.

For this, I tried to use Fermi's Golden Rule, which for a two-body decay states (according to Thomson's "Modern Particle Physics", page 66 ff.) that $$\Gamma_{fi} = \frac{p*}{32\pi^2m_a^2}\int \left| \mathcal M_{fi} \right|^2 d\Omega,$$ where generally the process $a \rightarrow 1+2$ was considered. If we invoked lepton universality, we might say that $\int \left| \mathcal M_{fi} \right|^2d\Omega$ is for both processes $\pi^{+}\rightarrow e^{+}\nu_{e}$ and $\pi^{+}\rightarrow \mu^{+}\nu_{\mu}$ equal. Now it remains to calculate $p^{*}$, which according to page 68 of Thomson is: $$p^{*} = \frac{1}{2m_a}\sqrt{\left[ m_a^2 - \left( m_1 + m_2\right)^2 \right]\left[ m_a^2 - \left( m_1 - m_2 \right)^2 \right]}.$$

Now I calculated $p^{*}$ both for $\pi^{+}\rightarrow \mu^{+}\nu_{\mu}$ and $\pi^{+}\rightarrow e^{+}\nu_{e}$, and obtain $9.74$ GeV for the latter case, and $4.16$ GeV in the former case. Hence, if I take the radio of the decay rates, I obtain that the process $\pi^{+}\rightarrow e^{+}\nu_{e}$ is approx. $\frac{9.74}{4.16} \approx 2.34$ more likely than the other one.

However, in another textbook, it states that the factor should be around $3.5$ and I'm left wondering where I made a mistake ...

Answer (score 1):

It is incorrect to say that $\int \left| \mathcal M_{fi} \right|^2d\Omega$ is the same for both processes. The matrix element contains kinematic components, and it is integrated over a different region of phase space for the two processes.

For a given set of momenta, $\mathcal M_{fi}$ is the same for both processes. But the momenta are not the same for the two processes, and so you will get a different result.

Comment: I cite Thomson, page 298: "Because the strength of the weak interaction for the different lepton generations is found to be the same (see Chapter 12), it might be expected that the matrix elements for the decays $\pi^{-}\rightarrow e^{-} \bar{\nu}_{e}$ and $\pi^{-}\rightarrow \mu^{-}\bar{\nu}_{\mu}$ would be similar". But I agree with you that it was sloppy of me to write "the same", maybe "similar" would have been better?

Comment: I also need to admit that the factor of 3.5 I wrote in my original question is for the processes $\pi^{-}\rightarrow e^{-}\bar{\nu_{e}}$ and $\pi^{-}\rightarrow \mu^{-}\bar{\nu_{\mu}}$ instead for the charge-conjugated processes ... Does this also make a difference for the ratios of the decay rates?

Comment: @MathIsFun For given momenta of all of the particles, they are the same. But the kinematics of the two processes are not the same. And the difference turns out to be *very* large in this case.

Comment: I'm just curious: How could I try to calculate $\mathcal M$ for both processes then, neglecting parity? We haven't had this in our lectures yet, but I would still like to understand.

Comment: @MathIsFun There are some decent lecture notes [here](https://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/~playfer/PPlect12.pdf). You can't really calculate $\mathcal{M}$ completely, but you can calculate it up to a constant that cancels out in the ratio.

Comment: I thought is was chirality suppressed, as the right handed anti lepton and the left handed neutrino have to have opposite spin direction (and they have opposite momentum direction), so one needs the wrong helicity....for which mass helps.

Comment: @JEB Yes, that is correct. The math for all of that is encoded in the integral of the matrix element over phase space.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the lecture notes!